# What is the best approach for performance when querying across multiple DB's

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a setup where our customers each have their own databases. We also have some shared databases that are used to hold things like module access, reports, customer server locations, etc.

We have a few queries that look like this

```
USING CustomerDB

SELECT 
    fields
FROM
    CustomerTable C 
    INNER JOIN SharedDb.dbo.SharedtableA A ON A.Id = C.SharedAId
    INNER JOIN SharedDb.dbo.SharedtableB B ON B.Id = A.SharedBId
```

Does it make a difference to query plans etc if we were to change the query so that it executes in separate spaces?

E.g

```
USE CustomerDb

DECLARE @SharedTemp TABLE (
    Id int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @SharedTemp
SELECT 
    Id
FROM
    SharedDb.dbo.SharedtableA A 
    INNER JOIN SharedDb.dbo.SharedtableB B ON B.Id = A.SharedBId

SELECT 
    fields
FROM
    CustomerTable C 
    INNER JOIN @SharedTemp A ON A.Id = C.SharedAId
```

Thank you in advance for your insights

Comment: Why not test and find out? Though I suspect the latter would be slowly, considering the additional writes into a table **variable** (it's not a temporary table, as it's name implies), and there's no initial filtering of the data.

Comment: Stick with your first example. Cross-database doesn't impact your query performance or plan in any measurable way. You could create synonyms for your sharedDb and not even reference it in your queries.